# How do I retain the copy and paste functions without having to store data in a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some functions doing a simple copy + paste but I need to parse the data before pasting it - I need to grab the left 3 characters.

So this is what I have now:

```
Set curr_ws = Worksheets("Data")
curr_ws.Range(data_curr_rng.Address(0, 0)).Copy

Set curr_ws = Worksheets(cal_name)
curr_ws.Range(site_curr_position.Address(0, 0)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

Is there a way to keep these and not have to store the data in a variable while parsing it?

Comment: What is wrong with storing it in a variable?

Comment: If you need the 3 left characters, I'm not sure why copy in the first place, unless you want formats (which you could easily copy/paste after grabbing the characters).

Comment: *I need to grab the left 3 characters.* Why? It's not clear what you're asking. You're not storing any values in any variables in your current code, and it's not clear why you need to parse the cell's contents prior to copying its contents, or what you intend to do with it as a result. Can you update your question with a more clear problem statement, including the desired output/result?

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying one cell, you can try a value transfer like below.

This avoids storing values in a variable **and** the clipboard!

```
curr_ws.Range(site_curr_position.Address(0, 0)).Value = _
Left(curr_ws.Range(data_curr_rng(Address(0, 0)).Value, 3)
```

Comment: Obviously would need a second worksheet cursor since I'm copying from and pasting to different worksheets

Comment: It avoids the clipboard. Avoiding variables is just the result of cramming it all into a single executable statement - which makes the code harder to debug when things later to wrong.

Comment: I suppose you could paste the value and then manipulate the value in that cell after the fact I suppose